# woocommerce catalog image thumbnails blurry

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an ecommerce website I am building on wordpress using woocommerce and I have come across an issue pertaining to the images on the catalog view only.

In the catalog the images look like this:
[image: catalog images]

See how the first two are darker and blurry and the third one is absolutely fine. All three images are 1100x1100px.

If you go onto the first products single product page it looks like this:
[image: single product image]

Pretty annoying and not a problem I've ever encountered before. I've tried regenerating thumbnails to the same size as the catalog size (309x309px) however this did not resolve the issue. I've also tried reuploading the photos however this didn't work either.

Any help/advice/ solutions heavily appreciated!

Development version of the site can be found [here](https://diamondcollectivedev.co.uk/mykspa/product-category/active-clearing/) for anyone who wants to take look.

Comment: If one is good and the others not, and they all have the same sizes, it probably depends from the original quality of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a regenerate thumbnails plugin and this resolved the issue:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/